# How to exit a bash loop and stop the script but only when all the iterations are completed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this code, which basically does a loop inside the DF command to see which disks are more than 90% full.

```bash
df -H | sed 1d  | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read -r dfh; 
do 
    #echo "$output" 
    op=$(echo "$dfh" | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1 ) 
    partition=$(echo "$dfh" | awk '{ print $2 }' ) 
    if [ $op -ge 90 ];  
    then 
        echo ">> ### WARNING! Running out of space on \"$partition ($op%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" >> LOGFILE 
        echo -e ">> ### WARNING! Running out of space on \"$partition ($op%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" 
        echo ">> There is not enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, exiting..." >> LOGFILE 
        echo -e ">> There is not enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, exiting..." 
        exit 1 
    elif [ $op -ge 85 ]; 
    then 
        echo -e ">> ### WARNING! Running out of space on \"$partition ($op%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" >> LOGFILE 
        echo ">> ### WARNING! Running out of space on \"$partition ($op%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" 
        echo ">> There enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, but it is recommended to first increase the size of the disk $partition" >> LOGFILE 
        echo -e ">> There enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, but it is recommended to first increase the size of the disk $partition"  
    fi 
done 
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; 
then 
    exit 
else 
    echo -e ">> There is enough left storage in the disk to continue with the upgrade, OK" 
fi
```

I want it to exit only if at least one disk is more than 90% full, that's the pourpose of the last if statement

The problem here is that the loop exits on the first disk recognised at more than 90%, this is bad because if I have 3 disks at more than 90% it will only report one of them (the first one in the loop) and then exit. Basically I want the script to report all the disks that are at 90% or more (and the ones that are at 85% too but without exiting, as you can read).

Is this possible?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `df -H | awk 'NR > 1{print $5, $1}' | while read -r op partition; do ...`. This leaves `%` in op, but avoids the malopropism/anti-idiomatic blasphemy of `op=$(echo | awk)`. You can trim the `%` either in the awk above or with `${op%%%}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script looks like it's screaming loudly to be refactored into Awk.  But here is a more gentle refactoring.

```
rc=0
df -H |
awk 'NR>1 { n=$5; sub(/%/, "", n); print n, $1 }' |
while read -r op partition; 
do 
    if [ $op -ge 90 ];  
    then 
        tee -a LOGFILE <<-________EOF
    >> ### WARNING! Running out of space on "$partition ($op%)" on $(hostname) as on $(date)
    >> There is not enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, exiting...
________EOF
        rc=1
    elif [ $op -ge 85 ]; 
    then
        tee -a LOGFILE <<-________EOF
    >> ### WARNING! Running out of space on "$partition ($op%)" on $(hostname) as on $(date)
    >> There enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, but it is recommended to first increase the size of the disk $partition
________EOF
    fi
    [ "$rc" -eq 0 ]
done &&
echo ">> There is enough left storage in the disk to continue with the upgrade, OK" ||
exit 1
```

This keeps track of `rc` while looping over all the partitions, then proceeds with the final condition only when the loop is done.

Generally, avoid `echo -e` in favor of `printf`, though here, since the `-e` wasn't doing anything useful anyway, a here document worked better.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

warn=${1-85}
fail=${2-90}

test "$warn" -lt "$fail" || { echo Invalid parameters >&2; exit 1; }

check_disk(){
    op=${1%%%}
    partition=${2}
    if test "$op" -ge "$warn"; then
        tee -a LOGFILE <<-EOF
            >> ### WARNING! Running out of space on "$partition ($op%)" on $(hostname) as on $(date)
            >> There is not enough left storage in the disk to perform the upgrade, exiting...
        EOF
    fi
    if test "$op" -ge "$fail"; then
        return 1
    fi
} 2> /dev/null

rv=0
df -H | awk 'NR > 1{ print $5 " " $1 }' \
| { while read -r op partition; do
    if ! check_disk "$op" "$partition"; then rv=1; fi
done
test "$rv" -eq 0
} || exit 1
```

A few notes:

You must have literal hard tabs as indentation if you want the `<<-` to suppress the indentation in the output.

You need to put the `while/done` in the brackets to give the `rv` variable the full scope to be able to check it.   If you just do `df ... | while do/done`, then the variable will be unset outside of the pipeline.

This is still a bit kludgy, and it would probably be better to do the whole thing in `awk` instead of having the `while/do` loop in the shell at all, but these are some ideas.  In particular, you definitely do not want to be writing the same `echo` line 4 times!

Also note that parsing the output of `df` is really fragile.  On my box, there are lines in which the filesystem column contains whitespace, so that the 5th column is *not* the current usage of the mountpoint.  This script will probably not work as desired on such output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one check, like this:

```
$ a=10 b=5  c=7 ; (( a>=10 && b>=10 && c>=10 )) && echo 'all >= 10'
$ a=10 b=5  c=10; (( a>=10 && b>=10 && c>=10 )) && echo 'all >= 10'
$ a=10 b=10 c=10; (( a>=10 && b>=10 && c>=10 )) && echo 'all >= 10'
all >= 10
```

Comment: If you have more than just 3-4 partitions, this is becoming untenable, though.